Flutter ExpansionTile Remove Title Padding
I'm using ExpansionTile to expand/collapse a widget.
I have a problem where the title has unwanted padding around it.
Tested all of the parameters but none of them seem to get the job done:


// my widget
ExpansionTile(
          controller: widget.controller,
          maintainState: !widget.rebuildOnExpand,
          title: widget.widgetClick,
          leading: widget.leading ?? const SizedBox.shrink(),
          trailing: widget.trailing, // ?? const SizedBox.shrink(),
          expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          onExpansionChanged: widget.onExpansionChanged,
          childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: widget.children,
        ),
        
// the rest of the settings inside ThemeData
ExpansionTileThemeData(
          tilePadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          expandedAlignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          iconColor: Colors.white,
        ),



The result (Note: I added a blue container around my title widget to demonstrate the problem):

My goal is for the title (the blue area) to fill up all available space between the left corner and the arrow on the right
Problem #2: Unwanted padding between title and children (red area = children)


You can now use minTileHeight & minVerticalPadding:
ListTileTheme(
  data: ListTileThemeData(
    minTileHeight: 0,
    minVerticalPadding: 0,
  ),
  child: ExpansionTile(


You can try :
ExpansionTile(
    childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    dense: true,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact ,//OR VisualDensity(vertical: -4) you change the number
    ...
)


This produces minor improvements

Can you send your code so I can check it

I'm using a simple Container as my title & children for testing.
I ended up solving this issue by separating the widgets among different ExpansionTile parameters: I assign the circle as the 'leading', the text as the 'title'

did you use : dense, tilePadding, visualDensity  OR childrenPadding ?

Yes, of course.

 visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal:-4,vertical:-4)

